# Copying git tags from one repository to another

Tags: git, tags

I've cloned a repository, changed it's origin and pushed to another server. Made sure to fetch all branches.

Later I realized that I did not push the git tags.

How can I add the original git tags to the new git server.

Comment: See if this helps https://gist.github.com/manakor/8972566

Answer (score 10):

When you clone a git repository, the tags are automatically copied over to your local repository.

But when you push your local git repository to a remote repository, the tags are not pushed by default. If you want to push only a specific tag, you can use something like

```
$ git push origin my-tag
```

Or if you want to push all your tags at once, you can do something like

```
$ git push origin --tags
```

---

Read more: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging#Sharing-Tags